# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. SuperOneClick

Tags: rooting

Im trying to root my Motorola Defy (not plus) and when going to root it with SuperOneClick (1.9.5) I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What can I do?

Comment: You file a bug report.

Comment: That is a very old version you have there, latest is v2.3.3, so that's probably fixed by now. Why are you using that specific version?

Comment: The site that hosted super one click to download you had to go through billions of adds -sigh- this was one I got from XDA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a bug that this specific version had, if you are using this specific version I strongly advise you to update.